# How i do it correctly to send my sqlite3 row to my HTML-body?

Tags: html, node.js, sqlite, send

I need to show my listings in my `html-body`.
I know how to send some `text` to listen.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("pass it?");
});
```

I need help to pass it into the `same site` where my `html` is.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
});
```

What i miss?

thx for the answer.

Comment: maybe try some template engine?

Comment: which kind of template, any Example?

Comment: looks like you're using `express`, https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar thanks, you was very helpfull =)